# My workflow ignores the path decided via Inputfunction

Tags: snakemake

I have two possible path for Trinity, genome free (GF) and genome guided (GG). For deciding which way to go I use the variable GUIDED from a config and depending on it i give the path to files created by either the GG or GF part.

The problem is that no matter what the Input function returns, snakemake always tries to run the GG part. (except for the exception ofc)

```
def GenomeDependentInput()->str:
guided = config["GUIDED"]
if guided == "GF":
    print(rules.aggregate_GF.output.fasta) #this print is run by snakemake and gives the correct path ...Results/trinityGF/{species}_Trinity_GF.fasta
    return rules.aggregate_GF.output.fasta
elif guided == "GG":
    print(rules.aggregateTrinity.output.fasta) # this is not (good)
    return rules.aggregateTrinity.output.fasta
else:
    raise ValueError("Please fill in the GUIDED variable in the config")
    

rule Transdecoder:
    input:
        fasta = GenomeDependentInput()
    output:
        pep = path.join(TRANS_DIR, "{species}", path.basename(GenomeDependentInput()) + ".transdecoder.pep")
    envmodules:
        config["PERL"],
        config["PYTHON3"]
    script:
        "scripts/TransDecoder.py"
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found that down the line another rule uses only the GG part and I had to use the GenomeDependentInput function there too.

Furthermore the Transdecoder rule wasn't even active as the Transdecoder output wasn't yet used as input.

Maybe this will help somebody else so I'll just leave this here.